# How to have an entrance animation on a UITableViewCell with Facebook POP

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, facebook-pop

I have been having problems using the Facebook POP animation library. I want to have an entrance animation on a UITableViewCell where the title label slides in from the right side of the screen. Is there any tutorial or documentation that will help me understand the library better so I could be able to use Facebook POP to its greatest capability? This will help me figure out my problem. I think that this problem is relevant to others too, because for beginners like me I think that for a great library like Facebook POP there should be more tutorials and documentation. So, can anyone point me in the right direction to animating the title label for the UITableViewCell?

Comment: Kudos to you for being a 14 year old developer!

Comment: I personally just switched to Canvas an animation library on Github which got the job done for me but still wasn't as flexible and powerful as Pop